# php if else condition not working

Tags: php, html

```
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));

$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];

$region = $geo["geoplugin_regionName"];

$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];

$continent = $geo["geoplugin_continentCode"];

$continent1 = $continent;

echo "IP: " .$user_ip. "<br>";

echo "City: " .$city. "<br>";

echo "Region: " .$region. "<br>";

echo "Country: " .$country. "<br>";

echo "Continent: " .$continent1. "<br>";
```

This code is for getting the IP and location details.

Here, my problem is, I am getting continents as AS, EU, NA, SA

I need to change AS to Asia, EU to Europe, NA to North America and SA to South America. How to use an `if else` condition for this?

Comment: Of course it's not working, there is no if/else statement in your code...

Comment: you need to use switch case for this http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Don't use if/else; use a lookup array (and an `if` just in case if your array is not exhaustive).

Comment: Bv202 i not that it wont work with that above code, did u read my question? i asked how to write..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
switch ($continent1) {
    case "AS":
        $continent1 = 'Asia';
        break;
    case "EU":
        $continent1 = 'Europe';
        break;
    case "NA":
        $continent1 = 'North America';
        break;
    default:
        $continent1 = '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

failing having this in a DB, you could try this:

```
$arr_continent = array('AS'=>'Asia','EU'=>'Europe','NA'=>'North America','SA'=>'South America');
echo "Continent: " .$arr_continent[$continent1]. "<br />";
```

it's a lot neater than a switch statement! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
switch ($continent)
{
    case "AS":
        $continent1 = 'Asia';
        break;
    case "EU":
        $continent1 = 'Europe';
        break;
    case "NA":
        $continent1 = 'North America';
        break;
    // rest of codes
}
```

[Php Switch Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function without any use of **if/else** or **switch statement**

```
<?php 
   function get_continent($continent_name){
      $arr = array(
        "AS" => 'Asia',
        "EU" => 'Europe',
        "NA" => 'North America',
        "SA" => 'South America'
        // and define more keys and value pair of continent short and full name
        );

      return ($arr[$continent_name]!="") ? $arr[$continent_name] : "N/A" ;
   }

   echo get_continent("EU");

   // output - Europe
   ?>
```

This code will also increase reuse-ability if you need similar task to be performed again and again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) method on your `$continent1` variable to replace the values with what you want

```
switch($continent1)
{
    case 'AS':
       echo "Continent: Asia";
      break;
    case 'EU':
       echo "Continent: Europe";
       break;
    case 'NA':
       echo "Continent: North America";
       break;
    case 'SA':
       echo "South America";
       break;
    default:
       echo "nothing matched"
      break;
}
```